# Connecting ionic app with php backend

Tags: php, mysql, ionic-framework

Here Im trying to learn how to use php+mysql as the backend to capture the request from this ionic ts file and insert these data to a table.

Im a total noob with ionic+php+mysql backend. Can someone could help me to carry out a solution?

```
createEntry(name, description)
   {
      let body     :  string  = "key=create&name=" + name + "&description=" + description,
          type     : string   = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
          headers  : any      = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': type}),
          options  : any      = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }),
          url      : any      = this.baseURI + "add.php";

      this.http.post(url, body, options)
      .subscribe((data) =>
      {
         // If the request was successful notify the user
         if(data.status === 200)
         {
            this.hideForm   = true;
            this.sendNotification(`Congratulations the technology: ${name} was successfully added`);
         }
         // Otherwise let 'em know anyway
         else
         {
            this.sendNotification('Something went wrong!');
         }
      });
   }
```

Edit:

What i have tried:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}



 $name   = $_REQUEST['name'];
 $description   = $_REQUEST['description'];


    $sql = "INSERT INTO table1(name,description) VALUES($name, $desc)";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);


   echo json_encode ($desc);
```

The values does not pass to the table.

Comment: Way to broad besides Stackoverflow isn't meant as tutorial website. But your code is from here http://masteringionic.com/blog/2016-12-15-using-php-and-mysql-with-ionic/.. "Im a total noob with ionic+php+mysql backend" then you should start with the basics and learn PHP, MySQL and ionic.

Comment: I have edited the above question.